# iOS 11: UIBarButtonItem inside UIToolbar goes out of its place

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

This is how my screen is supposed to look like. It has a UIToolBar at the bottom and its contains a UIBarButtonItem. It was working fine before before iOS 11.

[image]

But in iOS 11, the UIBarButtonItem is showing out its place. It is showing in the status bar. In the simulator it is working fine, and it shows inside the toolbar. But when I run it on an iPhone 6s running iOS 11. It's showing like in the screen below.

[image]

Here's the code..

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    UIBarButtonItem[] bArray = {
        getSetAsHomeButton(apiCall, this, 0),
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace)
    };
    SetToolbarItems(bArray, true);
}

public static UIBarButtonItem getSetAsHomeButton(ICommonApiCall commonApiCall, UIViewController controller, int status)
{
    var view = new UIButton ();
    view.Layer.CornerRadius = 8;
    view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

    view.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    view.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(108).Active = true;
    view.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(32).Active = true;

    var HomeIcon = new UILabel (new RectangleF (0, 0, 21, 21));
    HomeIcon.Font = FontAwesome.Font (22);
    HomeIcon.Text = FontAwesome.FAHome;
    HomeIcon.TextColor = PlatformConstants.PrimaryColor;

    var HomeLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (25, 0, 64, 44));
    HomeLabel.Text = "Set as default";
    HomeLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName (PlatformConstants.PrimaryFont + "-Medium", 11);
    HomeLabel.TextColor = PlatformConstants.PrimaryColor;
    HomeLabel.Lines = 0;
    HomeLabel.SizeToFit ();

    view.AddSubview (HomeIcon);
    view.AddSubview (HomeLabel);

    HomeIcon.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    HomeLabel.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    var hSpaceLeading = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (HomeIcon, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
                                   NSLayoutRelation.Equal, view, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 6);
    view.AddConstraint (hSpaceLeading);

    var HomeIconCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (HomeIcon, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
                               NSLayoutRelation.Equal, view, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0);
    view.AddConstraint (HomeIconCenterY);

    var HomeLabelCenterY = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (HomeLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
                               NSLayoutRelation.Equal, view, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0);
    view.AddConstraint (HomeLabelCenterY);

    var hSpace = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (HomeLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Left,
                            NSLayoutRelation.Equal, HomeIcon, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 4);
    view.AddConstraint (hSpace);

    var HomeLabelWidth = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (HomeLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
                              NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 80);
    view.AddConstraint (HomeLabelWidth);

    view.LayoutIfNeeded ();

    view.TouchUpInside += delegate {
        SetAsHome (commonApiCall, controller, status, view).ContinueWith (t => Console.WriteLine (t.Exception),
                                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    };

    return new UIBarButtonItem (view);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS Auto Layout has been introduced to the UINavigationBar and UIToolbar elements. So the best way to fix your problem is to add the proper constraints.

Here you can find some more help and details on the issue:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80075

Hope this solves your problem.